# Add instance to SimpleDiscoveryClient dynamically and programmaticaly - Spring Cloud

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

My question concerns this project https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons

Is there a way to add an instance to [SimpleDiscoveryClient](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/blob/master/spring-cloud-commons/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/client/discovery/simple/SimpleDiscoveryClient.java) dynamically and programmaticaly during runtime instead of using application properties like [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-commons/docs/current/reference/html/#simplediscoveryclient) ?

Some ideas :

- Create a custom implementation of SimpleDiscoveryClient
- Create a list of static instances besides SimpleDiscoveryClient (create respectively spring cloud gateway routes) and get instances from my static list and others from SimpleDiscoveryClient

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `SimpleDiscoveryClient` is a singleton bean. I've not tried it, but you could probably just autowire it to your class and manipulate it.

Comment: @spencergibb : Thanks for your help. I autowired SimpleDiscoveryProperties from SimpleDiscoveryClient to add an instance.

Answer (score 1):

Workaround : autowire SimpleDiscoveryProperties from SimpleDiscoveryClient to add an instance. Use ApplicationEventPublisher and send RefreshScopeRefreshedEvent to refresh Spring Cloud Gateway routes.

Comment: No need to hit an endpoint, just send the right Spring application event

Comment: @spencergibb I tried with ApplicationEventPublisher and send RefreshScopeRefreshedEvent, it seems to be working. Thanks a lot for the tips !

Comment: Thank you. DiscoveryClient contains a new/updated instance after the refresh. However, my load balanced webClient still tries to use the old instance from before refresh. Is there something else I'm missing?